# Obtain an App Access Token with Android FacebookSDK v3

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token

This is my first topic, I hope you can help me (please be nice with my English because my first language is french) thx :) )

I have a problem, I'm trying to get an app Access Token with the Facebook Android Facebook SDK v3 but I didn't succed so far.

I've seen on the internet that to get an app token we need to access that link :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token client_id=*************&client_secret=***********************&%20grant_type=client_credentials
```

So I made a request object to get the app token :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("client_id", appId);
bundle.putString("client_secret", appSecret);
bundle.putString("grant_type", "client_credentials");

Request request = new Request(null, "oauth/access_token", bundle, HttpMethod.GET);
Response resp = request.executeAndWait();
```

The object 'response' returns me a GraphObject as follow : 
    `GraphObject{graphObjectClass=GraphObject, state={"FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT":"access_token"}}`

But the access token is not containt in the response returned by the request.

However, when I launch the link in a browser I get a page like : 
`access_token=[the_access_token]`

Why can't I get the same thing whith a response?
Am I doing something wrong? Does anyone have a solution?

Thank you very much !

Comment: I think the fact that this endpoint’s response is _not_ JSON might be the problem – if your request object expects it to be JSON, but gets something else, it will probably fail. The message FACEBOOK_NON_JSON_RESULT indicates this as well.

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem.

the access token is not JSON type. so you can not use 'request' and 'response' of facebook api.
you will have solution under link.

[Show this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10816773/facebook-access-token-storing-in-android-app)

or see under code

---

```
public static void getAppAccessToken(){
    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="+CLIENT_ID+"&client_secret="+CLIENT_SECRET+"&grant_type=client_credentials";
    InputStream is;
    String result;
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    try{
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
             sb.append(line);
        }   

        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();
        result = result.split("=")[1];
        appAccessToken = result;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {

    }
}
```

---

Comment: never discuss your problems in others question,red FAQ for better understanding and if you answer for that,do mention it.